# In Bash or ZSH, is there an opposite to the `clear` command?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, zsh, inputrc

Typing `clear` into a shell creates a bunch of new lines until the output history above is all but hidden. Is there a command or method that does the opposite of clear? That essentially moves your current line you are editting to the middle or bottom of the screen, displaying the latest history of your shell above it?

The backstory to this, is that I am trying to map a key in bash/zsh's vi-mode to display previous history or previous output, but without losing the current command I am editting.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but try Shift+Page Up; in case that's what you're looking for there are ways to simulate the keystroke by running a command.

Comment: note that shift+mousewheel will do the same

Answer (score 2):

Navigating the output history is not the job of the shell (Bash/ZSH); they don't keep a record of the output the commands within them have produced. Output history is handled by the terminal, which today is typically either GNOME Terminal or xterm. Both of these support at least these shortcuts, as [mentioned by @kos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652499/in-bash-or-zsh-is-there-an-opposite-to-the-clear-command/652533#comment937514_652499):

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Page Up</kbd> to move at most one `$LINES` up
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Page Down</kbd> to move at most one `$LINES` down

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can bind a key to a command and so, for example, list the
command history whilst in the middle of typing a new command.
After the command runs your input line is restored at the point you
were originally at.

Eg, give the command

```
bind -x '"\C-a": history'
```

Then <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> will dump the history.

For permanence add to your ~/.inputc file

```
"\C-a": history
```

You can replace `history` by any command.

---

In zsh you have a built-in mechanism which pushes the current input buffer
onto a stack and allows you to give a new command. When it finishes, the
previous input buffer is restored.  So you type: <kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>
`history` <kbd>return</kbd>.

If you prefer you can setup a zsh widget binding to show the history *below* the current input buffer you are typing. Eg, for <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> again (in your `~/.zshrc`):

```
zle -N myhistory  
myhistory(){zle -M "$(history)";}
bindkey '^a' myhistory
```

---

To keep output history you might like to use `screen -L` which keeps a log
of all the output in a file, which you can tail with a binding as above. You might want to filter through `cat -e` or something, as the file includes
all terminal escape sequences.